# Using right ExecutorService to execute task asynchronously

Tags: java, asynchronous, concurrency, threadpool, executorservice

While processing a task I have to process 2 sub-tasks(basically steps) which can be done **asynchronously**.

I have created *Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()* and called it execute twice. Since it's single threaded pool does it mean 2nd sub-task(i.e. step 5 in below code) will be executed serially i.e. only after step 3 completes. Do I need to instantiate Executors.newFixedThreadExecutor(2) - with 2 as arguement as I need to execute only two steps asynchronously or what else should be done.

```
public class MyTaskImpl
{
private static final ExecutorService JOB_EXEC_SVC = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

public void doTask() throws Exception
    {
      // step 1
      // step 2
      // step 3 execute ASYNC
JOB_EXEC_SVC.execute(() -> step3(param1, param2));
      // step 4
      // step 5 execute ASYNC
JOB_EXEC_SVC.execute(() -> step5(param));
      // step 6
    }
}
```

Comment: Another option is using [CompletableFuture.runAsync](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#runAsync(java.lang.Runnable)), which uses a common ForkJoinPool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct. Since the `ExecutorService` you are using was created using `newSingleThreadExecutor`, step 5 will be completed after step 3 completes. In order to execute the two actions asynchronously, use `newFixedThreadExecutor`:

```
public class MyTaskImpl {

    private static final ExecutorService JOB_EXEC_SVC = Executors.newFixedThreadExecutor(2);

    public void doTask() throws Exception {
        // Step 1
        // Step 2
        // Step 3 (below)
        JOB_EXEC_SVC.execute(() -> step3(param1, param2));
        // Step 4
        // Step 5 (below)
        JOB_EXEC_SVC.execute(() -> step5(param));
    }
}
```

This however does not guarantee that step 3 and step 5 will execute parallel. For example, if step 4 takes a long time to complete, step 5 may be submitted to the `ExecutorService` (i.e. `execute` is called) after step 3 has already completed executing.

This is also true for the single-threaded case, but regardless of the time step 4 takes, step 5 will always be executed after step 3 completes (but it is indeterminate if step 5 is submitted when step 3 is running and blocks until step 3 completes, or if step 5 is submitted after step 3 completes).

Answer (score 1):

You are right. Because you use a single thread, so that thread is shared both of tasks. It's mean that these two tasks will execute asynchronously but they will execute serially, that is step 5 will execute after step 3. If you want step 3 and step 5 execute meanwhile, the Executors.newFixedThreadExecutor(2) is useful for this. You can use Executors.newCachedThreadPool() for more performance.